# Fill rectangle with noise and duplicate in a grid

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to fill a grid with duplicates of one rectangle filled with white noise.

I can create a grid with rectangle but can't fill them with noise. I can create white noise but can't fill a grid with it. Below the attempt to create the original. Now I would like to duplicate this in a e.g, 3x3 grid

```java
void setup(){

    size(900,900);
    background(0);
    stroke(255);
    noFill();
    noiseDetail(5);
    println(pixelWidth, pixelHeight);
}

void draw(){
    background(0);
    float scale = 0.01;
    int w = 300;
    int h = 300;

    loadPixels();
    for(int x = 0; x<w;x++){
      for(int y = 0; y<h;y++){
        float col = 255*noise(scale*x,scale*y,30*scale*frameCount);
        pixels[x + y*900] = color(col);
      }
    }
    updatePixels();
}
```

The result is a 300x300 rectangle filled with noise. I would like to have 9 of those in a grid with the same identical white noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to write a function, which renders the noise tile to [`PGraphics`](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) object:

```java
PGraphics CreateTile(int w, int h, float scale)
{
    PGraphics pg = createGraphics(w, h, JAVA2D);

    pg.beginDraw();
    for(int x = 0; x<w;x++){
      for(int y = 0; y<h;y++){
        float col = 255*noise(scale * x, scale * y, 30 * scale * frameCount);
        pg.set(x, y, color(col));
      }
    }
    pg.endDraw();

    return pg;
}
```

Then you can place the tile as often as you want you want:

```py
void draw(){
    background(0);

    int w = 300;
    int h = 300;
    PGraphics pg = CreateTile(w, h, 0.01);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            image(pg, w*i, h*j);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That was it. Perfect. The noise behaves a bit different. Not as smooth as in the single tile, but I guess that is another problem.